# Передать содержимое корзины Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть корзина на сайте, для оформления рассрочки банку нужно передавать содержимое корзины и цену. Итоговую стоимость передавать получилось, а как передать название товаров и количество в нужном виде - ума не приложу. Банк просит в таком виде:

```
<input name="itemName_0" value="Apple iPhone 7 256 GB Onyx" type="hidden"/>
<input name="itemQuantity_0" value="1" type="hidden"/>
<input name="itemPrice_0" value="59000.00" type="hidden"/> 
<input name="itemName_1" value="Apple iPhone 6 64 GB Onyx" type="hidden"/>
...
```

[image: корзина]

Comment: не люблю эти деревянные корзины, 20 века. =) И у `input` нет `.text()` метода, но зато есть `.val()` - заполняйте `input` и отправляйте, в чем сложность то?!

Comment: нашёл подсказку: 
    `<?php
    global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

        foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
            $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id()); 
            echo "<b>".$_product->get_title().'</b>  <br> '.$values['quantity'].'<br>'; 
            $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
            echo " ".$price."<br>";
    } 
?>`

но все-равно вопрос остается открытым для меня

Answer (score 0, accepted):

получилось вот так

```
<?php
    global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

        $mycount = 0;
        foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
            $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id()); 
            $tovar=$_product->get_title();
            $kolvo=$values['quantity'];
            $cena = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
            echo "<input name=itemName_$mycount value='$tovar' type=hidden>"; 
            echo "<input name=itemQuantity_$mycount value=$kolvo type=hidden>"; 
            echo "<input name=itemPrice_$mycount value=$cena type=hidden>"; 
            $mycount += 1;
            }
            ?>
```

только теперь проблема, если товар вариативный, то передается цена первой вариации, ищу решение

Comment: задал условия для простого и вариативного товара и все получилось